# Grails "assigned" ID Generation Strategy and beforeSave

Tags: hibernate, grails

In a domain class, I'm using the "assigned" ID Generator:

```
static mapping = {
    id(generator: 'assigned')
}
```

Before an entity is saved, I'd like to make sure that it has an id set.

```
def beforeSave() {
    if (!id) {
        id = DomainUtil.newId();
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, this does not work:

```
org.hibernate.id.IdentifierGenerationException: ids for this class must be manually assigned before calling save(): was.Product
```

The "beforeSave" hook seems to be invoked after the check for the id takes place. Is there a way to work around this? Im using Grails 2.1.1.

**EDIT:**

This seems to work, but it is quite hacky: On the propert declaration, I added:

```
String id = DomainUtil.newId();
```

This initializes the id with a "default", which can then be modified before calling `save()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try `beforeValidate`. It is probably the closest thing to what you are looking for. I'm not sure it will work in your specific case though. It will get executed on an insert or update because `save()` calls `validate()`.

Answer (score 1):

`beforeSave` isn't a supported GORM event. You want to use `beforeInsert`.

[relevant docs here](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/GORM.html#eventsAutoTimestamping)

Comment: You are right, don't know where I got that from. None the less, this event seems to be triggered after hibernate checks for the presence of the id, so I cannot use it in my specific case.